# Integrar estilos remotos en un proyecto local de Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap

Pues la pregunta es esa.
Me ha llegado una tarea en la que tengo que desarrollar el front de una aplicación web basándome en los estilos de la página que ellos ya tienen creada.

Me han hecho llegar capturas del head de HTML, donde enlazan a los plugin, pero esas rutas son relativas y yo no tengo sus assets.

¿Hay alguna manera de acceder a esos assets sin tener que replicar a mano toda la estructura de carpetas en mi proyecto local?

Si necesitáis algo más de información no dudéis en pedirla.
Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido ScaredJunior, ¿qué has hecho hasta el momento?

Comment: Si puedes acceder a esa página web, puedes obtener los ficheros de estilos. Si no, tendrás que pedirlos.

Comment: Hola! @David He revisado el cdn que me pasaron y descubrí que concretamente esas paginas no están protegidas por auth, asi que al final conseguí enlazarlas. Gracias!

Comment: @PabloLozano Gracias! Funcionó. Accedí por la URL completa. :D

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto con la siguiente etiqueta en el head

```
<script src="http://cdn.servidor/plugins/plugin.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
```